# How to index values according to another index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
       word
user       
a       dog
a       cat
a       cow
c       cat
c       dog
c     bunny
c      bird
f       dog
f      bird
```

I want to add another column that numbers the items in 'word' according to the index 'user', so the final table looks like this:

```
       word  number
user               
a       dog       1
a       cat       2
a       cow       3
c       cat       1
c       dog       2
c     bunny       3
c      bird       4
f       dog       1
f      bird       2
```

I was wondering what would be a good way to do this on a large dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `user` is on the index, so you have to do `.groupby(level=0)` prior to `.cumcount()`. `level=0` means you are grouping by the first index column. If there were two index columns, `level=1` would call the second:

```
df['number'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1
df
Out[1]: 
           word  number
user               
a       dog       1
a       cat       2
a       cow       3
c       cat       1
c       dog       2
c     bunny       3
c      bird       4
f       dog       1
f      bird       2
```